# How do I make a Python library fully functional without running an installer?

Tags: python, installation

I work for a corporation. I have a Windows 7 machine.
I want to be able to use FOSS Python libraries from GitHub. I can download all the libraries I want, but the company does not give regular users admin privileges to install a library.
They have a repository with specific versions of Python libraries, but it does not contain the libraries I need, such as Numpy, xlrd, or xlwt.

We have work that was assigned today and we have 2 weeks from today to get it done. The actual work is not relevant to this question and is also confidential, so I won't mention it. Even if we were able to get those specific versions of Python libraries, the requesting and installing process would take 2+ weeks, so that is not an option.

I only have Python 3.3 available to me. I cannot get pip, and even if I was able to, I would not be able to install anything without admin privileges.

Also, I cannot write anything to the C drive without admin privileges.

Is there a way to download and build the library without needing to install it? Basically just do the process of installing the library without having to run an installer.

Note: I have heard the terms "building from source" and "compiling from source" thrown around, but I do not know if they are relevant to my situation.

Comment: Can you import modules from the local directory?

Comment: Have you looked into using Python in the cloud?

Comment: Online IDE: https://repl.it/languages/Python

Comment: @What what do you mean by import modules from the local directory? I'm not too familiar with that.

Comment: Eventually, I need to be able to run the Python code with local data, so the cloud is not really an option. It can work for testing the code, but nothing further. Also, repl.it is blocked by my company's proxy.

Comment: @mrbobjrsrv a python script can be placed inside a directory and this directory can also contain modules which can be referenced in the script via `import`.

Comment: You should be able to test the code in the cloud and then use something to make a standalone executable from your Python script which you can then run on your local machine